# Should I return a floating point attribute in json as a number or a string?

Tags: javascript, json

I notice that sometimes when I return a json with a floating point field from a server endpoint, when it gets to the client it becomes a really long floating point number slightly off by a little. Say I return the following json from a server:

{
  'val': 6.85, ...
}

That 'val' when it gets to the client, it is still 6.85 in javascript, but with curl it becomes 6.84999999999, something like that. But if I return in string '6.85', then both look good (of course).

Is there an industry standard or general agreement or acceptance on this? Should I just return a floating point number in string in json?

Comment: I guess that depends on how you're using it.

Comment: Never heard about standarts with this. I assume that all depends on server that will parse your float.

Comment: From a numerical standpoint, they're the same (so it doesn't matter).

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing any arithmetic operation with that data?